# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat, gradlew

I have a question about one of the spring guides:

**Designing and Implementing RESTful Web Services with Spring**
I follow all the steps as described in the guide but I receive the following error when I try to use gradlew to execute the service as it is exactly mentioned in:
http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/3/

```
"C:\REST-Spring\workspace3\tut-rest-6-complete>gradlew tomcatRunWar
The ConfigurationContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the
create() method instead.
The TaskContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the create()
method instead.
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
rocessResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:war UP-TO-DATE
:tomcatRunWar
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/i827490/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.6-bin/72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok/grad
le-1.6/lib/logback-classic-1.0.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/REST-Spring/workspace3/tut-rest-6-complete/build/tmp/tomcatRunWar/work/Tomcat/loca
lhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory]
Started Tomcat Server
The Server is running at localhost
***No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'webservice'***
> Building > :tomcatRunWar"
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you created your controllers? What are they mapped to?

Comment: Yes, I imported the guide and it contains everything.